# C# Class Library "Make assembly COM-Visible" grey or not available

Tags: .net, vb6, visual-studio-2019, com-interop, class-library

I want to write a DLL in C# to use in VB6. When I looked it up i found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194639/Using-NET-DLL-in-VB). Sounds good to me, but i can't check the "Make assembly COM-Visible". I tried different Project types, but the "Assembly Information" button is either not there, or the "Make assembly COM-Visible" is greyed out. Any Ideas?

Im using:

- Visual Studio 2019 Community
- .Net Standard 2.0
- .Net Framework 4.8 SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These really is no magic.  COM-visible is an attribute you can add yourself:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute?view=netstandard-2.0

Registering your .NET dll can be done yourself as well, you don't need Visual Studio to do that for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool

If it is a private dll that doesn't need to be shared, you can use the /codebase option instead of putting it in the GAC.  The /tlb option can be used to generate the type library that the VB6 IDE will understand.

Comment: It can be very convenient to let VS manage the registration/unregistration for you. Especially until you figure out all the GUIDs that should be set, etc. and the interface (meaning TLB) isn't stable.

Comment: Perhaps.  I always found that it harmed me more than it helped.  The compiled and registered version typical sat in my filesystem along with the VB6 project it was created for.  Therefore when doing new dev on the one in the Visual Studio bin folder would cause it to re-register the one in that location, breaking the VB project.  I preferred to manually promote the in-dev one to the VB6 project myself once it passed all tests.

Comment: makes sense, but you might want to avoid colocating them if you don't have to, it makes it easier to make use of the ones in the VS output location, assuming the DLL doesn't care where it is physically located to operate properly.